# Main differences between Hash Table Linear, Quadratic, and Separate Chaining

Tags: java, hashtable

Where does Linear get different than Quadratic?

In terms of put and get and expanding(resizing the hash table)

Also with Quadratic to separate chaining, how does it differ in code ..

As I have kept this algorithm for linear, but I don't know how the others differ:

1. Retrieve key k
2. Compute hash function h[k]= k %size of the table
3. If hash table is empty at the computed hash value place
         then insert key at h[k]
   else
       we need to find another empty place in the hash table to insert the key in the table

Answer (score 0):

> Also with Quadratic to separate chaining, how does it differ in code

This sounds like an incongruent question. Linear/quadratic are different probing techniques within the same design space of open-addressed hashtables, whereas separate chaining is the other space (close-addressed).

Your algorithm matches *any* open-addressed scheme, including quadratic probing. Probing enters the story in your last step, "find another empty place". With linear probing you just step through the array one by one, whereas with quadratic probing you use a quadratic formula to tell you where to look next.